# performance difference between String.valueof(char) and string literal

Tags: java

I came upon some CONSTANT definitions in a project, and was wondering why they were defined as String.valueOf(' ') instead of " ".

```
//how it is defined
public static final String SPACE = String.valueOf(' '); 

//how I would do it, so I don't have the String.valueOf() overhead..
public static final String SPACE2 = " ";
```

anyone that has a clear answer for this one?

Comment: someone just wanted to be "smart", in a non-smart way I guess

Comment: No real difference. The  `valueOf()` is just helpless.

Comment: There is actually *a* difference. According to source code `valueOf(char)` creates new `String` object. Calling `valueOf` with the same char several times, consequently, creates several equal, but distinct objects (that may or may not end up sharing their internal representation array eventually, after `intern()` is run).

Comment: in this case it appears that it is only run once for each character, so except for the useless function-call, it has no real effect then.

Comment: Not true. It may be run once in this class, then someone runs it in other class or uses `char c = <get>; if (Constants.SPACE.equals(String.valueOf(c)) ...`, and the "it's run only once" situation is no longer applies. Literals, however, will remain literals. Compiler tracks whether there is one literal or several.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov the source code of `String.valueOf` is an implementation detail. There could be different implementations, further, there could be JVM side optimizations just replacing the invocation with a known result. The contract doesn’t say anything about the identity of the result. So, even without looking at the source code, comparing an unspecified identity with the string literal, we know what to prefer, as you nailed it, “Literals, however, will remain literals”.

Comment: @Holger, it is an implementation detail indeed, which is why this was a comment, not answer. However, since this is a question about performance, it is very much concerned with implementation details. I do feel that the only real answer to this would be a pointer to JMH though.

Comment: And what would JMH be? (can't recall if I encountered this abbreviation before)

Comment: @ShadowFlame It’s a benchmark tool, see http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Comment: @M.Prokhorov benchmarking will also only tell you something about a particular implementation. Of course, when it comes to performance, you shouldn’t ignore the reality of particular implementations, especially the common ones, but still, you should also consider the general case. So even if HotSpot/OpenJDK had an implementation of `String.valueOf(char)` that returns a canonical string, it wasn’t a guaranteed property. So using a literal, which has a guaranteed behavior of evaluating to a canonical instance is preferable, regardless of the implementation.

Comment: Since it is static, the code is only run once. Maybe you could measure a difference for one million invocations, if it wasn't static but you shouldn't care - a case of premature optimization.